# SQL Server - Table has Composite Primary Key

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a composite primary key in my table. Question, wouldn't this be a clustered index to begin with in which case I would not need to define it as being a clustered index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the primary key will default to include a clustered index as long as there is not already a clustered index on the table, and as long as you don't explicitly specify a non-clustered index.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342.aspx):

> When you create a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, a unique clustered index on
>   the column or columns is automatically created if a clustered index on
>   the table does not already exist and you do not specify a unique
>   nonclustered index. The primary key column cannot allow `NULL` values.